# python multiprocess using map, but with one sub-process running

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool

I am new to python `map()` function to achieve parallel code.

```py
def main_function(sample):
    # ......(only input file; calculations; and output file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_sample_common = os.listdir('/lustre/scratch/Stat/s1155136154/ONT_Panel2')# WES,ONT_panel, Pacibo_Panel intersection.
    list_sample_Pacibo_normal = ['RMH12', 'RMH15','RMH20','RMH25','RMH3.','RMH7.','RMH9.']# normal people sample
    list_sample_ONT_cDNA_only = ['RM66T','RM68T','RM77T']
    sample = list_sample_common + list_sample_Pacibo_normal + list_sample_ONT_cDNA_only
    pool=Pool()
    pool.map(main_function,sample)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So when I first use it on the cluster, the sub-process are run with 500% CPU (since I apply 5 cores in the cluster).

However, after some time, there is  only one core running:
[image: top result]

So, the reason for that is the main function containing the output and input operations? And due to the main process only passing the short list to the sub function, I am sure the parameter size won't influence the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an educated guess since I do not know enough about the size of `sample` and the details of the work being performed by your worker function, `main_function`

Lets assume that the *iterable*, `sample`, that you are passing to the `Pool.map` method has length 70 and as you said your pool size is 5. The `map` method will break up the 70 tasks into `chunksize`-sized groups of tasks distributing these chunks to each of the 5 processes in the pool. If you do not specify the `chunksize` argument to the `map` method it computes the value based on the size of the iterable (70) and the size of the pool (5) as follows:

```py
def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, pool_size * 4)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize
```

So for your values, `chunksize` will be 4. So there will be 17 chunks of tasks of size 4 and a smaller 18th chunk of size 2 distributed among the 5 processes (each column is a queue of tasks for a given process in the pool):

```
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 2
```

Assuming all tasks took an equal time to process, you could see that after a certain amount of time the last 2 processes would have completed the 12 tasks given to them and would now be idle and you would be running at only 60%. Eventually the third process will complete its tasks and and you will be now running at 40%.

But you can see for the right combination of `sample` size and pool size, you could have a situation where you will only be running one process. This is exacerbated with large `chunksize` values, which are meant to reduce the number of shared memory accesses required to queue up tasks but can lead to some inefficiencies in CPU utilization.

As an experiment, try re-running your program explicitly specifying a `chunksize` argument of 1 for your `map` invocation. Unless the number of tasks is a multiple of your pool size and every task takes the same amount of time to complete, even then you cannot expect every processor to have a task to run. **In fact, it would be rare to have a situation where you had something *other* than only one process left running a final task.** But this should reduce the percentage of time that only one processor is busy. But using a `chunksize` of 1 is considered inefficient for large iterables.

**Demo With Pool of 4 Processes Where the First Process Gets All the Long Running Tasks**

Here 16 tasks are submitted with a `chunksize` of 4 to a pool size of 4 so that the first process gets the first 4 tasks to run and these are artificially made to be 10 times longer running than the rest. We return an identifier associated with the sub-process to demonstrate that one particular process is processing the first 4 tasks:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
import re
import time

def get_id():
    m = re.search(r'SpawnPoolWorker-(\d+)', str(current_process()))
    return int(m[1])

def worker(i):
    R = 10000000
    id = get_id()
    t = time.time()
    # run up the cpu:
    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(R * 10 if i <= 3 else R):
        cnt += 1
    return i, id, time.time() - t



if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)
    # 4 tasks per process:
    results = p.map(worker, range(16), chunksize=4) # first process gets arguments: 0, 1, 2, 3
    for result in results:
        i, id, elapsed_time = result
        print(f'i={i}, process id={id}, elapsed time={elapsed_time}')
```

Prints:

```
i=0, process id=1, elapsed time=6.197998046875
i=1, process id=1, elapsed time=5.889002323150635
i=2, process id=1, elapsed time=5.952000856399536
i=3, process id=1, elapsed time=6.022995948791504
i=4, process id=2, elapsed time=0.6909992694854736
i=5, process id=2, elapsed time=0.8339993953704834
i=6, process id=2, elapsed time=0.5869994163513184
i=7, process id=2, elapsed time=0.7560005187988281
i=8, process id=3, elapsed time=0.7500002384185791
i=9, process id=3, elapsed time=0.7440023422241211
i=10, process id=3, elapsed time=0.7600002288818359
i=11, process id=3, elapsed time=0.7479968070983887
i=12, process id=4, elapsed time=0.7950015068054199
i=13, process id=4, elapsed time=0.7909986972808838
i=14, process id=4, elapsed time=0.8639986515045166
i=15, process id=4, elapsed time=0.7230024337768555
```

**Important Note:** I may have said something was a simplification of what really occurs. There is a single input queue of tasks. Tasks are placed on this queue in chunks of `chunksize` groups and a process in the pool when it is idle takes the next `chunksize` group off the queue to process. I implied in my diagram that these chunks were pre-dealt out to all the processes at the start, but that is not necessarily the case. In my demo above I chose a `chunksize` that essentially caused all the chunks to be dealt out (the *default* `chunksize` would have been 1 if not specified). But sometimes it is even possible for the first process to grab all the chunks if the processing of the tasks is trivial (e.g. just a `return None` statement), which was not the case in the above demo. The implication of having a single queue with all the chunks is that when the `chunksize` is 1, a processor should never be unnecessarily idle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try it. Actually, the sample is a list with length 56. I think, it is not big. So set the chunk size to 1 would work. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that even with a `chunksize`  of 1 where all the tasks are distributed as evenly as possible across all the processes, one of the processes could possibly have longer-running tasks and although all the other processes have finished processing all of its tasks, that one process may have N tasks left to process and it is too late to re-distribute the work to the other idle processes.

Comment: Also, one more question: does the map_async ( ) has better performance than map ( ) in this situation ?

Comment: Thanks Booboo, I understand. The final time will be decided by the heaviest sub-task.

Comment: I have added a demo and an important note to clarify something I said which was an oversimplification.

Comment: The call to `map` blocks until all the tasks submitted complete. You would only call `map_async`, which does not block and instead returns an `AsyncResult` object, if there is *more* tasks you also want to submit in parallel with the work already submitted. `result = pool.map(arguments)` is implemented as: `a_r = pool.map_async(arguments); result = a_r.get()`

Comment: Okay! Thanks for you clarification, I understand now.